# Java program to send an email using microsoft outlook in selenium is throwing "javax.mail.MessagingException:"

Tags: java, selenium

Below is my sample code where am trying to send an email through gmail.

```
public class Sendmail {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String username = "";  // like yourname@outlook.com
        final String password = "";   // password here

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");



        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("Valid email address"));   // like inzi769@gmail.com
            message.setSubject("Test");
            message.setText("HI you have done sending mail with outlook");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

But eachtime i try to run this piece, i end up with an exception

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;"
```

I have tried changing the port numbers, but still no use. Can someone please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.
​​

Change your settings to allow less secure apps to access your account. We don't recommend this option because it might make it easier for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access anyway, follow these steps:

1. Go to the [less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1) section in My Account.
2. Next to "Access for less secure apps," select **Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users:** This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);

    mailSender.setUsername("my.gmail@gmail.com");
    mailSender.setPassword("password");

    Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    return mailSender;
}
```

And then you can send the mail as below

```
@Autowired
public JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendSimpleMessage(
  String to, String subject, String text) {
    ...
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
    message.setTo(to); 
    message.setSubject(subject); 
    message.setText(text);
    emailSender.send(message);
    ...
}
```